# Why does hidden content affect layout, even with overflow hidden on the parent?

Tags: css, less

I am attempting to animate a block of content (collapsing 5 seconds after display), which is working, but I have this artifact where the `display: none` content after the collapse transition is still affecting layout, even when specifying `overflow: hidden`.

The code is as follows (and [here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGydRo), as I am getting errors in the SO code runner):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  $('#container').addClass('closing')
}, 5 * 1000)
```

```css
#container {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  min-height: 4rem;
  opacity: 1;
  .step {
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    & * {
      transition: all linear 0.5s;
    }
  }
  &.closing {
    min-height: 0rem;
    height: 0rem;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    & * {
      overflow: hidden;
      min-height: 0rem;
      height: 0rem;
      padding-top: 0rem;
      padding-bottom: 0rem;
    }
  }
}
#bottom-block {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container" class="ui closing steps">
  <div class="completed step">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Shipping</div>
      <div class="description">Choose your shipping options</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="completed step">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Billing</div>
      <div class="description">Enter billing information</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="active step">
    <i class="info icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Confirm Order</div>
      <div class="description">Verify order details</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom-block">
  Testing
</div>
```

I have hacked around in the Styles on chrome to see if I can figure out what is causing this, but even when manually removing all the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, it is still not fully collapsing.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

(Note also that I am not using JQuery in the real code, but rather am setting classes through state management in React. Not relevant, just wanted to avoid "Why not use JQuery animations?" replies.)

**Update:**
[Here is the forked codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXeBEB) with the implemented change from below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.ui.steps` element has display inline-flex: therefore it's an inline element that is represented by a `line box` (https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-css3-box-20070809/#line-box.).

It will occupy at least one line-height of vertical space in it's parent element, in this case the body element.

To illustrate that try reducing the font-size and line-height of your body: you'll see the space shrink. Of course hacking font-size is not a good solution, you can't even make it totally disappear because most browser will ignore font sizes of 0.

Edit : as @cmprogram have said, using display: none is usually the best move here.
Also, there is no such thing as `display:hidden`, I think you are confusing with `visibility:hidden`

Comment: See my reply to @cmprogram.

Comment: Well then you'll have to use display: flex to prevent spawning a line box

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is located in your

> display: inline-flex;

Try using:

> display: block;

or

> display: flex;

instead.